# Calculating the Line Total Amount in the table JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an invoice view for my asp.net MVC project.

Currently, the selected item is added to the table and there it shows the Item Name, Qty, and Amount.

I want to add the Line amount also. The current one I have added shows the total amount when the item is added to the table. But when I increase the qty. It is not calculated.

Can you help me to solve this?

This is my HTML Code.

```
 <div class="table-scroll-container">
   <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="tableModi invoice-table">
       <!-- Table header content -->
       <thead>
         <tr class="tr">
           <th class="th" width="50%">Item</th>
           <th class="th" width="20%">Qty</th>
           <th class="th" width="10%">(%)</th>
           <th class="th" width="20%">Amount</th>
           <th class="th" width="20%">Line Total</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="itemTableBody">
         <!-- Table rows will be added dynamically using JavaScript -->
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
         <tr>
           <td style="border: none; text-align: right">SUBTOTAL:</td>
           <td style="border: none"></td>
           <td class="amount subtotal" id="totalAmount">0.00</td>
           <td class="docEdit"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td style="border: none; text-align: right">DISCOUNT:</td>
           <td style="border: none"></td>
           <td class="amount subtotal" id="discount">
             <input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" oninput="limitDiscountValue(this)" onchange="updateTotalAmount()" value="0.00" /> %
           </td>
           <td class="docEdit"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td style="border: none; text-align: right">TAX:</td>
           <td style="border: none"></td>
           <td class="amount subtotal" id="tax">0.00</td>
           <td class="docEdit"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td style="border: none; text-align: right">NET AMOUNT:</td>
           <td style="border: none"></td>
           <td class="amount subtotal" id="netAmount">0.00</td>
           <td class="docEdit"></td>
         </tr>
       </tfoot>
     </table>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This is how I added the Item to the table

```
function addItemToTable(item, button) {

  var itemTableBody = document.getElementById('itemTableBody');

  // Check if the item is already in the table
  var existingRow = itemTableBody.querySelector(`tr[data-item-id="${item.ID}"]`);

  if (existingRow) {
    // If the item is already in the table, update the quantity
    var quantityCell = existingRow.querySelector('.item-quantity');
    var quantity = parseFloat(quantityCell.textContent);

    // Get the available quantity from the data attributes of the row
    var availableQuantityAttr = existingRow.dataset.availableQuantity;
    var availableQuantity = availableQuantityAttr ? parseFloat(availableQuantityAttr) : 0;

    // Check if the current quantity is less than the available quantity
    if (!isNaN(availableQuantity) && quantity < availableQuantity) {
      item.Quantity++;
      quantityCell.textContent = item.Quantity;
    } else {
      // Show toaster message for available quantity exceeded
      toastr.error('You cannot exceed the available quantity');
    }

  } else {
    // If the item is not in the table, create a new row
    var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
    newRow.setAttribute('data-item-id', item.ID);
    newRow.setAttribute('data-available-quantity', item.AvailableQuantity);

    var nameCell = document.createElement('td');
    nameCell.textContent = item.Name;

    var removeButton = document.createElement('button');
    removeButton.textContent = 'X';
    removeButton.className = 'remove-item-button';
    removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      removeItemFromTable(item, newRow);
    });
    // Add margin to the right of the remove button for space
    removeButton.style.marginRight = '8px';

    nameCell.insertBefore(removeButton, nameCell.firstChild); // Insert the remove button before the item name

    newRow.appendChild(nameCell);

    var quantityCell = document.createElement('td');
    quantityCell.className = 'item-quantity';

    // Set the default quantity to 1 for new items
    item.Quantity = 1;
    quantityCell.textContent = item.Quantity;

    // Set the available quantity as an attribute on the quantity cell
    quantityCell.dataset.availableQuantity = item.AvailableQuantity;

    // Create the up arrow icon for increasing quantity
    var upArrow = document.createElement('span');
    upArrow.innerHTML = '&#9650;'; // Up arrow Unicode entity

    upArrow.addEventListener('click', function () {
      increaseQuantity(upArrow);
    });

    // Create the down arrow icon for decreasing quantity
    var downArrow = document.createElement('span');
    downArrow.innerHTML = '&#9660;'; // Down arrow Unicode entity

    downArrow.addEventListener('click', function () {
      decreaseQuantity(downArrow);
    });

    quantityCell.appendChild(upArrow);
    quantityCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' ')); // Add space between the arrows
    quantityCell.appendChild(downArrow);

    var discountCell = document.createElement('td');
    discountCell.className = 'item-discount';

    var discountInput = document.createElement('input');
    discountInput.type = 'number';
    discountInput.min = 0;
    discountInput.max = 100;
    discountInput.value = 0; // Set the default discount to 0 for new items

    // Add an event listener to the input to update the total amount when the discount changes
    discountInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
      updateTotalAmount();
    });

    var amountCell = document.createElement('td');
    amountCell.className = 'item-amount';
    amountCell.textContent = item.Amount.toFixed(2);

    var editCell = document.createElement('td');
    editCell.className = 'btn-container';

    var lineTotalCell = document.createElement('td');
    lineTotalCell.className = 'item-line-total';

    // Parse quantity and item amount as numbers
    var quantity = parseFloat(quantityCell.textContent);
    var amount = parseFloat(item.Amount);
    var lineTotal = quantity * amount;
    lineTotalCell.textContent = lineTotal.toFixed(2); // Initialize with the line total

    //var decreaseButton = document.createElement('button');
    //decreaseButton.className = 'btn-decrease';
    //decreaseButton.textContent = '- 1';
    //decreaseButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //    decreaseQuantity(this);
    //});

    //var increaseButton = document.createElement('button');
    //increaseButton.className = 'btn-increase';
    //increaseButton.textContent = '+ 1';
    //increaseButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    //    increaseQuantity(this);
    //});

    //editCell.appendChild(decreaseButton);
    //editCell.appendChild(increaseButton);
    discountCell.appendChild(discountInput);

    newRow.appendChild(nameCell);
    newRow.appendChild(quantityCell);
    newRow.appendChild(discountCell);
    newRow.appendChild(amountCell);
    newRow.appendChild(lineTotalCell);
    /* newRow.appendChild(editCell);*/
    var quantityInput = newRow.querySelector('.item-quantity');
    quantityInput.addEventListener('input', function () {
      updateLineTotal(this, lineTotalCell, item.Amount);
      updateTotalAmount(); // Update the Total Amount as well
    });

    // Disable the button temporarily to prevent multiple clicks
    if (button) {
      button.disabled = true;
      setTimeout(function () {
        button.disabled = false;
      }, 1000); // Enable the button after 1 second (adjust the delay as needed)
    }
    itemTableBody.insertBefore(newRow, itemTableBody.firstChild);

    // Remove the last row from the table body if the maximum number of visible rows is exceeded
    if (itemTableBody.childElementCount > maxVisibleItems) {
      itemTableBody.removeChild(itemTableBody.lastChild);
    }

  }
  updateTableContainerHeight();
  updateTotalAmount();
}
```

This is the line total calculation

```
function updateLineTotal(quantityInput, lineTotalCell, itemAmount) {
  var quantity = parseFloat(quantityInput.textContent); // Use textContent to get the value
  var amount = parseFloat(itemAmount);
  // Calculate the Line Total
  var lineTotal = quantity * amount;
  // Update the Line Total cell
  lineTotalCell.textContent = lineTotal.toFixed(2);
}
```

This is the increase and decrease the quantity

```
function increaseQuantity(upArrow) {
  var row = upArrow.parentElement.parentElement;
  var itemId = parseInt(row.getAttribute('data-item-id'));
  var item = items.find((item) => item.ID === itemId);
  if (item) {
    var quantityCell = row.querySelector('.item-quantity');
    var quantity = parseInt(quantityCell.textContent);
    var availableQuantity = parseInt(quantityCell.getAttribute('data-available-quantity'));
    var itemAmount = parseFloat(row.querySelector('.item-amount').textContent);
    var lineTotalCell = row.querySelector('.item-line-total');
    var lineTotal = parseFloat(lineTotalCell.textContent); // Use parseFloat here

    console.log(quantity, lineTotal, itemAmount);
    updateLineTotal(quantity, lineTotal, itemAmount);

    if (!isNaN(availableQuantity) && quantity < availableQuantity) {
      quantity++;
      quantityCell.textContent = quantity;

      toggleArrows(row, quantity, availableQuantity);
      updateTotalAmount();
    } else {
      toastr.error('You cannot exceed the available quantity');
    }
  }
}

function decreaseQuantity(downArrow) {
  var row = downArrow.parentElement.parentElement;
  var itemId = parseInt(row.getAttribute('data-item-id'));
  var item = items.find((item) => item.ID === itemId);
  if (item) {
    var quantityCell = row.querySelector('.item-quantity');
    var itemAmount = parseFloat(row.querySelector('.item-amount').textContent);
    var lineTotalCell = row.querySelector('.item-line-total');
    updateLineTotal(quantityCell, lineTotalCell, itemAmount);
    var quantity = parseInt(quantityCell.textContent);
    if (quantity > 1) {
      quantity--;
      quantityCell.textContent = quantity;
      toggleArrows(row, quantity);
      updateTotalAmount();
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the Sub total Calculation.

```
 function updateTotalAmount() {
   var itemTableBody = document.getElementById('itemTableBody');
   var rows = itemTableBody.querySelectorAll('tr');
   var totalAmount = 0;
   rows.forEach(function (row) {
     var itemId = parseInt(row.getAttribute('data-item-id'));
     var item = items.find((item) => item.ID === itemId);
     if (item) {
       var quantityCell = row.querySelector('.item-quantity');
       var quantity = parseInt(quantityCell.textContent);

       totalAmount += item.Amount * quantity;
     }
   });

   var totalAmountCell = document.getElementById('totalAmount');
   totalAmountCell.textContent = totalAmount.toFixed(2);
 }
```